# Is there any possibility to recreate manifest inside different class loader?

Tags: scala, reflection, osgi, scala-2.10

**Update** - original question isn't ambiguous and leads to abstract discussion.

The clarification is in update.

I have `immutable.HashMap[Manifest[_], _]` that is generated by 3rd party library inside classloader A.

- A key `Manifest[MyClassX]` that contains shared classes will preserve his `hashCode` when `HashMap` is passed class loader boundary.
- A key `Manifest[MyClassY]` that contains classes from different class loaders will become unusable.

`Manifest[MyClassY]` inside class loader **A** and `Manifest[MyClassY]` inside class loader **B** have different `hashCode` value.

*I want to know is Scala reflection library has an ability to recreate `Manifest[_]` from class loader **A** inside class loader **B**?*

FYI. After that I will compare the original manifest and a new one.

```
If hashCode is the same then
  we have `Manifest[MyClass]` with `MyClass` from shared origin.
else
  we have Manifest[MyClass] with MyClass from different origins.
```

I need to detect and separate keys of HashMap by this constraint.

---

**Original**.

I have OSGi environment and I have manifest **m** with hash code *123* withing bundle **A**.
I want to check if this manifest 'is the same' for available classes in bundle **B**.

If I pass manifest to bundle **B** then:

- if bundles have common class loader for manifest classes after I will recreate manifest **m'** with reflection it must have the same hash code *123*
- if bundles have different class loaders then I will have manifest **m'** with hash code *987* even manifest class names are the same. Hash codes the same classes are different if classes were loaded by different class loaders.

Is there any way to recreate manifest by reflection? I don't want to process all possible manifest fields, call for each one `Class.forName(...)` and then compare `hashCode` with origin.

Is there any other possibility to achieve the same target?

I bound to manifests by external library.

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to check - will hash code of two Manifest[MyClass] be the same withing two different bundles. For some bundles this will true (with common classloader), but for some - false.

Comment: I could read that, but for what reason do you want to do that? It might help to understand what you're trying to do because I fail to see why this (as far as I understand the description) has a practical use. So I am probably missing something.

Comment: Library pass to bundle at runtime from somewhere `HashMap[Manifest[T],_]`. I must detect invalid keys. Some keys are valid so `map.get[Manifest[MyClass]]` returns Some(...), some keys are not. Because `Manufest[A].hashCode` in bundle **A** not always is `Manifest[A].hashCode` in bundle **B**.

Comment: I must detect such situations and fix configuration of classloaders or fix code that depends on such keys.

Comment: Still do not understand what you try to achieve? How do you describe to your boss/customer (assuming she is not technical) what you are spending their money on?

Comment: Thank you very much for interest Peter. I'm prefer not to discuss about financial effectiveness here. I have technical problem and I want to solve it. I must admit that OSGi is not a tool that allow to gather money in most optimal way. Thank you.

Comment: @Ezhik, your issue is the result of the design decisions you/your company have made.  Perhaps by explaining what you want to **achieve**, people like Peter can direct you to a better design that doesn't require such shenanigans.

Comment: :-( I have *concrete technical question*. It is **low level** operational case that have no relation with tactical or strategic decision. If I want to discuss about architecture this will be another question. All components are in places. I just need a hint about *concrete situation* in *concrete programming language*. And I will solve it anyway. Stackoverflow community may find better solution of this **concrete** situation: recreating `Manifest[_]` object within different class loader.

Comment: Well if you don't tell us about the context where you need something rather strange, the Stackoverflow community has no idea how to help you, that's why Peter asked the questions.

Comment: The problem is your question is not clear to me, knowing the WHY might give it the lacking sense. Might be me, or the fact that English is not your first language. However, I'll try to answer what _might_ be the question.

Comment: Updated. Clarified. Question is about http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.Manifest